# Implementing a function to recurse through a AST inn LLDB

Tags: c, algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree, lldb

I am trying to recurse through a Binary AST. The AST is built by the compiler. I can look up through the informations in the AST through LLDB. But I want to be able to recurse through the tree using a function. How do I execute this function in the lldb command line?

```
p *N->invariantList->constraints->irLeftChild->irRightChild->irLeftChild->irLeftChild->irLeftChild->irLeftChild->irLeftChild->type
```

The above is the way I look up through the tree at the moment.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke a function that exists, or write a new bit of code to do the recursion?

Comment: new bit of code to do the recursion

Comment: although there is an existing function in the code base to do this, I am not sure how to call the function.

Comment: The `print` commands' (actually the `expression` command - print is an alias) job is to "run the expression provided as though it had been typed into the current frame.  So you should be able to call the extant function the same way you would if you were doing it in code.  Sometimes (because of missing debug info) you have to be more explicit about casting types.  Is that not working?